how can i resolve this error : "LightGBMError: Label 754 is not less than the number of label mappings (31)"
I see the following using lightgbm (the LightGBM Python package):

LightGBMError: Label 754 is not less than the number of label mappings (31).

I am training LAMBDA MART in listwise dataset of Letor collection, this dataset contains 64 features.
How can i resolve it?
import lightgbm as lgb
def evaluate_population(population,file_path):
if 'query_id' not in df.columns or 'relevance' not in df.columns:
    raise ValueError("DataFrame must contain 'query_id' and 'relevance' columns")
evaluations = []
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
le = LabelEncoder()
df['relevance'] = le.fit_transform(df['relevance'])
result= pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns)
for individual in population:
    selected_indices = [i for i, bit in enumerate(individual) if bit == '1']
    print(selected_indices)
    if not selected_indices:  # Avoid empty subsets
        objective1 = len(file_path) + 1  # Penalize empty sets
        objective2 = 1.0  # Maximum error
    else:
        queries = df['query_id'].unique()
        print(queries)
        selected_data = []

        for query in queries:
            query_data = df[df['query_id'] == query]
            num_docs = len(query_data)

            
            if len(individual) < num_docs:
                individual = individual.ljust(num_docs, '0')

            mask = [int(bit) for bit in individual[:num_docs]]
            #print(mask)
            assert len(mask) == num_docs, "Mask length must match the number of documents"
            selected_docs = query_data.iloc[mask]
            selected_data.append(selected_docs)

          # Combine all selected documents
        result = pd.concat(selected_data)
       
        group = create_group(result['query_id'])
        train_data = lgb.Dataset(result.drop(['relevance', 'query_id'], axis=1), label=result['relevance'], group=group)

       
        params = {
            'objective': 'lambdarank',
            'metric': 'ndcg',
            'learning_rate': 0.05,
            'num_leaves': 31,
            'min_data_in_leaf': 20,
            'lambda_l1': 0.1,
            'lambda_l2': 0.1,
            'max_bin': 255,
            'num_iterations': 100,
            'ndcg_eval_at': [1, 3, 5]
        }


    
        ranker = lgb.train(params, train_data)

     
        predictions = ranker.predict(df_imputed.drop(['relevance', 'query_id'], axis=1))

        # Evaluate the ranking accuracy using NDCG on the training set
        ranking_accuracy = ndcg_score([df['relevance'][df['query_id'] == q] for q in queries],
                                      [predictions[df['query_id'] == q] for q in queries])


        objective1 = len(selected_indices)  # Number of instances
        objective2 = 1 - ranking_accuracy  # Inverse ranking accuracy

    evaluations.append((individual, objective1, objective2))
return evaluations

Can anyone please help me?

Welcome to LightGBM. Please review "How to create a minimal, reproducible example" (link). I personally know how to answer this question, but in general it'll be difficult to get high-quality answers here without details like the versions of the libraries you're using and a fully self-contained code sample. And you can make it easier for others to test this by reducing to the smallest code necessary to demonstrate the issue (I strongly suspect lambda_l1 and lambda_l2 could be left at their default values, for example).

can u pleas help me
